# Abstract properties as own value objects

Tags: oop, domain-driven-design, abstraction, value-objects

Given the following example:

```
class Person {
  Integer age
  String lastName
  String firstName 
}
```

The property **age** should be constrained to specific validation rules:
 - Higher than 0

Same for the **lastName** and **firstName**:
 - These strings should not contain special characters (e.g. numbers, underscore, ...)
- Length should be > 0

---

In order to abstract this validation policy, should I create value objects such as **age** and **name** in order to encapsulate the validation:

```
class Age {
  Integer value
}

class Name {
  String value
}

class Person {
  Name lastName
  Name firstName
  Age age
}
```

Indeed I can also keep the code DRY and re-use my value objects but it seems like an "over-abstraction"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sidebar: [falsehoods programmers believe about names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/).

> should I create value objects such as age and name in order to encapsulate the validation

It's a trade off: the creation of a value type allows you to limit the number of places that validation is required in your program.

With a strong type checker, using a specific type allows the compiler to protect the programmer from a class of errors.

Furthermore, the creation of value types gives you a natural home for methods related to the state.

It also insulates the consumers of Age from the in memory representation; for example, if you were to later decide that you wanted to change the *units* of age, or that age should track the specific time that was age=0, then you can make that change in one place, rather than everywhere.  This is right from [Parnas](https://blog.acolyer.org/2016/09/05/on-the-criteria-to-be-used-in-decomposing-systems-into-modules/) -- `Age` serves as a boundary around the decision to use an integer representation in memory.

The question "where are we using age in our code" is a lot easier to answer when age is not merely a domain agnostic type.

Against that - it adds does add some complexity to introduce value types.

In many cases, the benefits of defining domain specific types outweigh the costs.